# Design Patterns in Delphi

Tags: design-patterns, delphi

Delphi has a few problems implementing some design patterns because some features it lacks, like multiple inheritance and no pure abstract classes.

Are there any good resources or "Adaptation-Patterns" to convert some or all of the Design Patterns in the GoF book, to Delphi applications?

Comment: What necessities are there for multiple inheritance in implementing which design patterns?

Comment: "Delphi has a few problems implementing some design patterns because of the necessity of multiple inheritance."?  Please provide an example or two.

Comment: @Frank I shouldn't have played up multiple inheritance in my question, there are other factors that make design patterns in the "Design Patterns" book not easily translatable to Delphi.  But I believe the adapter pattern uses Multiple Inheritance.  I'm not a pattern user so I can't me to defend my non-existent knowledge.  I've just found the examples in the book difficult to translate into Pascal.

Comment: @Peter Turner: Java and C# don't have multiple inheritance, but they still implement the Adapter pattern. Look up how they do it to get some hints...

Comment: "I've just found the examples in the book difficult to translate into Pascal."  I'm sure that's true.  But we can't imagine what's "difficult" for you.  Could you provide a specific example of a pattern and the specific Pascal-related questions you have?

Comment: @S.Lott Maybe on StackOverflow

Comment: Here's an [old resource](http://www.obsof.com/delphi_tips/pattern.html), the first thing I get when searching for "Delphi Design Patterns"

Comment: I'm talking about objective difficulty in terms of the translation of the pattern isn't possible in 1-to-1 (like lifting a C++ merge sort algorithm)

Comment: Counter-existence proof: GoF gives examples of patterns in Smalltalk, a single-inheritance language.

Comment: It's not just multiple-inheritance, I just plain old don't see a whole lot of Delphi code that uses design patterns.  Probably because there aren't a lot of Delphi programmers using design patterns.   So either A. There is something about delphi that makes it so code written using the language doesn't use Design Patterns all that often or B. There is something about Delphi programmers than make them less likely to use design patterns.

Comment: @PeterTurner Your conclusion is in error.  Delphi is a much less popular language than Java for example, and it is unfortunate for the 'image' of the language that a large number of Delphi developers - in my experience - don't really understand either the language, or how to write software. As I mention in my answer, the VCL is filled with pattern implementations. They may however be slight variations on some of the standard patterns you have seen before.  Use patterns as a guide, but remember that they may not be an exact fit for a given problem and would require tuning.

Answer (score 4):

A pure abstract class is just an interface in Delphi. And since Delphi allows a class to implement as many interfaces as possible, that should really remove the worst burden.

Answer (score 2):

The VCL is literally filled with implementations of patterns, many of which have come straight out of the GoF book itself.

I think that one problem that many people have when using Delphi is that Delphi allows a class with abstract methods to be compiled and used at run time provided the abstract methods are not called. The only thing that is purely abstract are Interfaces. Everything else that is needed for class inheritance and supporting multiple interfaces works with Delphi, so I can't really see how you would have any difficulty implementing ANY of the GoF Patterns. I've certainly never had any difficulty in the 14 or so years that I've been using the language.

As for multiple inheritance, what does that have to do with patterns?  Multiple inheritance is rife with problems conceptually, particularly if you are attempting to implement a descendant of two classes that present interfaces where there are identical methods with slightly different implementations. Which one would be used, and how would you choose? Interfaces solve this problem very elegantly in that you can use many interfaces in a single class implementation, and at different levels of the ancestry of a class.

If you have problems implementing specific patterns, perhaps a question on ProgrammersSE with some example code would help you to gain a better understanding about ways to overcome a particular problem in Delphi.  I'm sure they would make great questions.

Cheers,

Answer (score -3):

The Design Patterns as presented in the GoF book are very heavyweight solutions. I would consider them over engineering in many cases. I would suggest implementing the patterns using much simpler class structures.

I think it is the complexity of the structures you are trying to recreate, rather than the patterns themselves, that are causing you problems.